# When using JSQMessagesViewController as detailView in UISplitviewCOntroller, KeyBoardToolBar needs to appear in DetailViewController only

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

When using JSQMessagesViewController as detailView in UISplitViewController, KeyBoardToolBar needs to appear in DetailViewController only

[image]

Comment: couldn't get your question?

Answer (score 0):

late answer...

if u want to reduce the `inputToolbar` you need to create a subclass of `JSQMessagesToolbarContentView` and provide your own view for the tool bar's content view.

below i am giving the sample example, create a subcalss of `JSQMessagesToolbarContentView` name it as `JSQMessagesToolbarContentView_custom` in the subcalss add below code,

```
#import "JSQMessagesToolbarContentView.h"

@interface JSQMessagesToolbarContentView_custom : JSQMessagesToolbarContentView
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *holderViewLeadingConstraint;
@end
```

and in `JSQMessagesToolbarContentView_custom.m` file,

```
#import "UIView+JSQMessages.h"
#import "JSQMessagesToolbarContentView_custom.h"

@implementation JSQMessagesToolbarContentView_custom

+ (UINib *)nib
{
      return [UINib nibWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([JSQMessagesToolbarContentView_custom class])
                      bundle:[NSBundle bundleForClass:[JSQMessagesToolbarContentView_custom class]]];
}

#pragma mark - Initialization

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
   [super awakeFromNib];
   [self setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
   self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}

//below method will place the contentview to desired position 
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
   [super layoutSubviews];
   self.holderViewLeadingConstraint.constant = 320;
}

#pragma mark - Setters

- (void)setBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)backgroundColor
{
   [super setBackgroundColor:backgroundColor];
   self.leftBarButtonContainerView.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
   self.rightBarButtonContainerView.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
}

- (void)setLeftBarButtonItem:(UIButton *)leftBarButtonItem
{
   [super setLeftBarButtonItem:leftBarButtonItem];  
}

- (void)setLeftBarButtonItemWidth:(CGFloat)leftBarButtonItemWidth
{  
   // self.leftBarButtonContainerViewWidthConstraint.constant = leftBarButtonItemWidth;
   [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
}

- (void)setRightBarButtonItem:(UIButton *)rightBarButtonItem
{
   [super setRightBarButtonItem:rightBarButtonItem]; 
}

- (void)setRightBarButtonItemWidth:(CGFloat)rightBarButtonItemWidth
{  
   //  self.rightBarButtonContainerViewWidthConstraint.constant = rightBarButtonItemWidth;
   [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
}

- (void)setRightContentPadding:(CGFloat)rightContentPadding
{
   // self.rightHorizontalSpacingConstraint.constant = rightContentPadding;
  [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
}

- (void)setLeftContentPadding:(CGFloat)leftContentPadding
{
   //  self.leftHorizontalSpacingConstraint.constant = leftContentPadding;
   [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
}

#pragma mark - UIView overrides

- (void)setNeedsDisplay
{
    [super setNeedsDisplay];
    [self.textView setNeedsDisplay];
}


//return the custom view that we are going to create next 
- (JSQMessagesToolbarContentView_custom *)loadToolbarContentView
{
   NSArray *nibViews = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[JSQMessagesToolbarContentView_custom class]] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([JSQMessagesToolbarContentView_custom class])  owner:nil  options:nil];
  return nibViews.firstObject;
}
```

after this you need to create add new `.xib` file name it as `JSQMessagesToolbarContentView_custom.xib` this file contains our small content view for the `inputToolbar` and more importantly set the out let connections as doing the demo example and aslo set the view class name to `JSQMessagesToolbarContentView_custom`. hear i can only add image of the custom view.

[image]

now create a outlet for leading constraint to reduce the size of the content view as give below,

[image]

and add the constraints  outlet's as given in the demo. so if u add some constrians without modifying the base class it will give error or runtime error so edit the base class also

now go to `JSQMessagesToolbarContentView.h` and add the blow properties form `JSQMessagesToolbarContentView.m` just cut and past and make it public.

```
@interface JSQMessagesToolbarContentView : UIView

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *leftBarButtonContainerViewWidthConstraint;


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *rightBarButtonContainerViewWidthConstraint;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *leftHorizontalSpacingConstraint;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *rightHorizontalSpacingConstraint;

//...rest of the code
```

now in the `JSQMessagesInputToolbar.m` file, in order to make the tool bar transperent for half of the splitview,

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
     //...rest of the code
    [self setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]//imageNamed:@"topbar"]
              forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny
                      barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [self setShadowImage:[UIImage new] forToolbarPosition:UIBarPositionAny];
    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

}
```

thats it now run the project, and change the leading constraints constant you see below output,

[image]